# Windows version of Chrome 56 random "L" superscript sprinkled in text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, frontend

This is an original wordpress theme built for a client. On Windows only, Chrome is generating random L superscripts throughout the text.

Looked in the generated html, nothing erroneous, just literally a random L inserted in the DOM that isn't supposed to be there

Here is a view of the [site](http://qbrelis.com/). Any suggestions?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please include a screenshot so the question wont die when the website goes down anytime in the future.

Comment: How was the code created? What editor was used? It might actually be this character http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0003/index.htm

Comment: Agree with @j08691 as it seems related to fonts used/editor used.